# Query from only matching sub category in wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a category called "projects". I would like to query the various subcategories only if they match. How do I do this? The code below just queries all children of the main category "projects".

```
if (is_single()) {
    $cats = get_categories('child_of=31');
    $cat = $cats[0];

} else {
    $cat = get_category(get_query_var('cat'));
}
$cat_slug = $cat - > slug;
$work_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'work',
    'category__in' => array($cat - > term_id),
    'posts_per_page' => 20,
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'paged' => $paged,
    'post__not_in' => array(get_the_ID()),
));
```

Comment: If they match what? Also this is wrong: `array($cat - > term_id),` write it without extra spaces `array($cat->term_id),`

Comment: I need it query just from the same subcategory of "projects"